# Rendering style bundles bundles not the same as style links

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, layout

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses the Metronic template from keenthemes.

When i use bundles in my layout for my css , it doesnt work well. Most of the ***icons*** do not appear

If i switch to direct links then everything is ok.

Javascript is ok.

**Bundles config and layout use:**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/metronic-app").Include(
    "~/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "~/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css",
    "~/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css",
    "~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css",
    "~/assets/global/css/components.css",
    "~/assets/global/css/plugins.css",
    "~/assets/admin/layout2/css/layout.css",
    "~/assets/admin/layout2/css/themes/default.css",
    "~/assets/admin/layout2/css/custom.css"));


@Styles.Render("~/bundles/metronic-app")
```

**Direct links:**

```
<link href="~/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
<link href="~/assets/global/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/assets/global/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/assets/admin/layout2/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link id="style_color" href="~/assets/admin/layout2/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/assets/admin/layout2/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Here are the errors from chrome console:**

[image: console errors]

Answer (score 0):

I should have been using the `CssrewriteUrlTransform` class in my bundle configuration in order to make the asset's paths absolute.

What worked is this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/metronic-app").Include(
                "~/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css",
                "~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css",
                "~/assets/global/css/components.css",
                "~/assets/global/css/plugins.css",
                "~/assets/admin/layout2/css/custom.css")
                .Include("~/assets/admin/layout2/css/layout.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
                .Include("~/assets/admin/layout2/css/themes/default.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
                .Include("~/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
                .Include("~/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css",new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Hint from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700385/font-awesome-not-working-bundleconfig-in-mvc5)