# Style bundler rendering link incorrectly

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

This is a new MVC5 project, created from the blank ASP.NET template.

Here's my bundle registration:

```vb
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Class BundleConfig
  Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(Bundles As BundleCollection)
    Bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/styles/main").Include("~/Styles/Layout.css"))
  End Sub
End Class
```

...here's the relevant section of my view:

```html
@Code
  Me.Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>

  @Styles.Render("~/styles/main")
</head>
```

... and here's the HTML output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>

  <link href="/styles/main" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Note that the link's href should instead be:

```html
  <link href="/Styles/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

All of this of course results in a `404` error.

Things I've tried:

1. Followed the general guidance from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)
2. Added a `CssRewriteUrlTransform` object, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26197909)
3. Both enabled and disabled Optimization, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271866)
4. Updated the `WebGrease` package to the latest version
5. Checked `Web.config` for an `umbracoReservedPaths` key, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26197909) (none exists)
6. Added `Bundles.IgnoreList.Clear()` as indicated [here](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/asp-net-mvc-bundle-rendering)

This exact construct is working correctly in another project, so obviously something's different. But I'm unable to spot it.

How can I get this bundle to render properly?

Comment: You called it `"~/styles/main"` so that is what it is

Comment: `~/styles/main` is the key (note the tilde, which isn't rendered in the incorrect link). The renderer is supposed to return `/Styles/Layout.css` for that key. This same construct also works correctly in another project.