# font-awesome not working bundleconfig

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

I posted last year on the same issue. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700385/font-awesome-not-working-bundleconfig-in-mvc5) 
 But this time I did same as previous but I am having error different. Now font is looking root level like this.

```
http://www.dev.com/Content/font-awesome-4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
```

config

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/specss").Include(
     "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/Css/site.css",
    "~/Content/Css/sidenav.css",
    "~/Content/overlay.css").Include("~/Content/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css", 
                                       new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

[image]

but it suppose to look at `http://www.dev.com/iapps/ebiz/Content/font-awesome-4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0` other bootstrap and else working fine.

Comment: What is the path to fonts folder in `font-awesome.css`?

Comment: `../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0`

Comment: If you move `font-awesome.css` out of the folder and simply throw it in the `Content` folder, and change it in your `BundleConfig` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

On my current project, I have mine set up as:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/site.css",
    "~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"));
```

I'm not familiar with the CssRewriteUrlTransform class, but I just include my font awesome css right in the same Include method as the other css sheets.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found is to recompile the css with **less** or **scs**, according to font-awesome documentation http://fontawesome.io/get-started/.

In my opinion, using **StyleBundle** and **CssRewriteUrlTransform** is a more flexible approach, but it seems that this is impossible for latest versions (i'm using the 4.7.0).

Comment: That link seems to imply that css would work fine without recompiling.

Comment: it works only using <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> but it don't if you use StyleBundle for optimization.