# bootstrap fontawesome icon is not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons

when i am using **fa fa-inr** for displaying rupees icon

```
<div class="inner-addon left-addon editor-field">
     <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price,new { @class = "form-control"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
```

it not works properly[for fontawesome icon -  rupee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Xo2.png)

it works when i am using glyphicon icons.

```
<div class="inner-addon left-addon editor-field">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></i>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price,new { @class = "form-control"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
```

it works properly[for glyphicon icon -  euro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1rqE.png)

Comment: Please look though the similar questions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave reference of **fontawesome-all.min.css** instead of fontawesome.min.css and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [font-awesome not working bundleconfig in MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700385/font-awesome-not-working-bundleconfig-in-mvc5#22700610)

Looks like your font-awesome css is not properly referenced.
Also, looks like you are using HTML Helpers through razor and maybe bootstrap.

The best choice for ASP.NET MVC is to bundle it so you may need to use the following format with `.Include` inside your Bundle.config:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/Foo.css",                        
            "~/Content/Bar.css",
            "~/Content/Boo.css",
            "~/Content/Far.css"
        ).Include("~/yourpath/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

Maybe update your NuGet package and then recheck that your reference is correct.

If all else fails, an easy fix is to put this CDN link in your `<head></head>` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

if you use the CDN link, make sure you're not also referencing a font-awesome.css file in your project. Check Bundle.config and make sure to delete the reference.

http://ericpanorel.net/2013/10/25/font-awesome-4-0-mvc-bundling-and-minification/